# Passport Azure AD authentication in GraphQL Server Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, apollo-server, passport-azure-ad

hoping someone can help a noob with some async javascript issues.

I am attempting to secure a GraphQL server instance using Passport and the passport-azure-ad strategy.
I can see from logs that the incoming Access Token is validated correctly and all of the passport code is working as expected.

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const OIDCBearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;

...

// Setting up the Strategy and verify function
const bearerStrategy = new OIDCBearerStrategy(options, (token, done) => {
  if (!token.scp.includes('check-this-scope')) {
    return done(null, false, { message: 'User not authorized to access resource' });
  }
  return done(null, token);
});

passport.use('oauth-bearer', bearerStrategy);

...

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async (context) => {
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', (authErr, authUser, authInfo) => {
      if (!authUser) context.authErr = authErr || authInfo;
      else context.user = authUser;
    })(context.req, context.res);
    return context;
  },
});
```

The authErr and authUser params are correctly being passed to the custom callback, however the context is returned before the callback is executed.

Ideally I would like to `if (!user) throw new AuthenticationError('you must be logged in');` in the context block if the user is not available, however due to the asynchronous nature of the code I don't have access to it.

How can I make the code in the context wait until the custom passport.authenticate callback has executed? Or alternatively is there a better way for me to do this?
I am new to apollo server, passport and even working with node, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was doing something wrong.

Right now it seems that my setting of `context.user` isn't even available in the context delivered to the resolvers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to "promisify" you authenticate request:

```
const authOauthBearer = ({ req, res }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', (authErr, authUser, authInfo) => {
    if (!authUser) reject(authErr || authInfo);
    else resolve(authUser);
  })(req, res);
});
```

and then use it in the context like this:

```
context: async (context) => {
  try {
    const { user } = authOauthBearer(context);
    context.user = user;
  } catch(error) {
    // you may want to escalate the auth issue to the client so you can just throw:
    // throw error;

    // or you can store the auth error in the context
    context.authError = error;
  }
  return context;
}
```

Comment: Hi @brmk, thanks for that, I think you're right and the above would work. Ultimately I just ended up rolling my own auth client for this purpose since it was a relatively simple task; and not many clients specifically support the Azure On-Behalf-Of auth flow.

Also I just didn't really like Passport that much, I felt it was a bit too specifically designed as a web server middleware, and the documentation left a bit to be desired. Too many examples not enough actual reference docs.

Comment: Great. I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-passport as a binding utility to wire up passport and Apollo server. Passport is good fit having so much support and integrations, but I agree with you regarding the learning curve. It has to much stuff hidden and not obvious to understand right from the start. Would you mind still accepting my answer as a solution to your question by clicking on a tick button?